# Android - Updating progress bar from for loop in separate thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I'm new to android and don't have much experience with threading. I want to create a progress bar that actually progresses realistically. The progress bar is needed due to a for loop that processes an array with roughly 370,000 words and appends the ones that match user input to a TextView. This can take anywhere from 1-10 seconds depending on how precise the user's input is. Given that the progress bar has to be running on a separate thread, is there a way I can update its progress from inside the forloop?

This is the method with the aforementioned forloop (Line 15 sets a value that can be used to update the progress bar and line 16 hypothetically updates progressBar):

```
    public void matchWords(char[] exLettersArray, String word, String[] array, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    char[] guessWordChars;
    char[] curWordChars;
    int wordLength = word.length();
    guessWordChars = word.toCharArray();
    boolean matches = true;
    char unknown = '-';
    TextView generatedList = findViewById(R.id.generated_list);
    generatedList.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());

    int progress;

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //Iterates through every word in the array

        progress = ((i + 1) / array.length) * 100; //Convert to %
        //progressBar.setProgress(progress);

        if(array[i].length() == wordLength) {
            curWordChars = array[i].toCharArray();
            for(int j = 0; j < wordLength && matches == true; j++) { //Iterates through every character in a word
                for(int k = 0; k < exLettersArray.length; k++) { //Iterates through all letters to be excluded
                    if(curWordChars[j] == exLettersArray[k]) { //Makes sure that the current word does not contain exLetter
                        matches = false;
                    }
                }
                if(guessWordChars[j] == unknown) {
                    //System.out.println("found unknown variable at index " + j);
                    for(int q = 0; q < wordLength; q++) {
                        if(curWordChars[j] == guessWordChars[q]) { //Makes sure that already known letters are not used for unknown letters
                            matches = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    if(guessWordChars[j] == curWordChars[j]) {
                        //System.out.println(array[i] + " passed comparison of element " + j + " flag is " + matches);
                    }
                    else {
                        matches = false;
                        //System.out.println("guessWord char " + guessWordChars[j] + " != " + "curWordChars " + curWordChars[j] + " set flag to " + matches );
                    }
                }
            }
            if(matches == true) {
                generatedList.append(array[i]);
                generatedList.append("\n");
            }
        }
        matches = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AsyncTask is what you are looking for, https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.

You would want to place your `for` loop in the `doInBackground` method, and you can update your UI in `onProgressUpdate`. Anything that takes longer than a few milliseconds to execute or blocks your UI, you should do it off of the main thread. This is why you would add your code to the `doInBackground` method.

`onPostExecute` runs after your code in `doInBackground` completes and is executed on the main thread. You can update your UI here.

Here is a really short example based off of your code:

```java
private static class MatchWordsTask extends AsyncTask<String[], Integer, Boolean> {
    private WeakReference<ProgressBar> mProgressBar;
    private String[] mArray;

    MatchWordsTask(ProgressBar progressBar, String[] array) {
        mProgressBar = new WeakReference<ProgressBar>(progressBar);
        mArray = array;
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(String[]... arrays) {
        for (int i = 0; i < mArray.length; i++) {
            publishProgress(((i + 1) / mArray.length) * 100);

            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mProgressBar.get().setProgress(progress[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean matches) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Matches: " + matches);
    }
}
```

You would execute this AsyncTask like this:

```java
String[] array = new String[]{"This", "is", "an", "array", "of", "words"};
new MatchWordsTask(progressBar, array).execute(array);
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need.

Comment: @SlaviPaskalev Awesome! Please accept the answer if it answers your question.